# How do I divide taxonomy term pages by content type?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Drupal out of the box lists all of the content tagged with a term in a single list on a terms page. I would like to split up that list into sub pages based on content types tagged with that term. See mockup below. Seattle is the term page and the "Attractions, Museums, Restaurants and Shopping" are content types tagged with "Seattle". To achieve this, i cannot use quicktabs as it requires an admin to create a new quicktab collection everytime a new city is created. Also, panels is not an option on this project either. I am thinking it they are just views pages, with a term id from URL contextual filter, but I am lost on how to add them as secondary tabs on the term page. Unless I am heading in the worng direction. I would love some advice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A couple approaches come to mind, I will outline the one that does not use panels.

Start by overriding the default taxonomy page by enabling the one that comes with views.  At this point you will have the same behavior as the default taxonomy pages.

Clone the default taxonomy view and disable the clone (this is case you want to restore the view).

Now back to the taxonomy view

Remove the existing two contextual filters  (not this means the depth feature will no longer be available)

Add a contextual filter on "Content: Has taxonomy term ID"
Add another on "Content: Type".

Change the path to "taxonomy/term/%/page" (for page use the content type machine name you want for this tab)

Change "menu" setting to "default menu tab"

(A) Clone the "Page" display, I gave by clone the name of the content type for the tab

(B) Change the path so "page" is replaced with the next content type you want.

(C) Change "menu" setting to "menu tab"

Repeat (A) (B) and (C) for each content type/tab